# Datatables Throwing Invalid JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am facing issues with the [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin while fetching data using SSP. I had used the [Custom SSP](https://github.com/emran/ssp) library, but that is returning an error of Invalid JSON response. Anybody here who has implemented the custom SSP library? I will have to use `JOINS`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, etc. I am also open to suggestions on how to implement a Live Filtering function in tables using PHP as shown in the example table [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). So if you guys have any idea on how to implement this without using Datatables, that would also work fine.

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

**Initialisation**

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      colReorder: true,
      "scrollX": true,
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "rep_down_data.php"
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

**The one with the JOIN query. The Custom SSP Library has been used here.**

```html
<?php
$table = 't_user';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'is_phone_verified', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'mobile_number',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name',     'dt' => 3 ),
 array( 'db' => 'last_name',     'dt' => 4 ),
    array( 'db' => 'rep_code',     'dt' => 5 ),
);
require('config.php');
$sql_details = array(
 'user' => $db_username,
 'pass' => $db_password,
 'db'   => $db_name,
 'host' => $db_host
);
require('ssp.customized.class.php' );
$joinQuery = "FROM `t_user` AS `u` JOIN `t_user_course` AS `ud` ON (`ud`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`)";
echo json_encode(
 SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery )
);
```

**This is running fine and has the Datatables SSP file (rep_down_data.php)**

```html
<?php
$table = 't_user';
$primaryKey = 'id';
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'created_at', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'email',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'mobile_number',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name',     'dt' => 3 ),
 array( 'db' => 'last_name',     'dt' => 4 ),
);
require('config.php');
$sql_details = array(
 'user' => $db_username,
 'pass' => $db_password,
 'db'   => $db_name,
 'host' => $db_host
);
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

**The HTML code for the table**

```html
<section id="column-filtering">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">Rep Downloads</h4>
          <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="la la-ellipsis-v font-medium-3"></i></a>
          <div class="heading-elements">
            <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
              <li><a data-action="collapse"><i class="ft-minus"></i></a></li>
              <li><a data-action="reload"><i class="ft-rotate-cw"></i></a></li>
              <li><a data-action="expand"><i class="ft-maximize"></i></a></li>
              <li><a data-action="close"><i class="ft-x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content collapse show">
          <div class="card-body card-dashboard">
            <table id="example" class="display nowrap table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Enr. Date</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Mobile Number</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Enr. Date</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Mobile Number</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post your actual code, not screenshots

Comment: @Darren I have edited the post with the screenshots. Do let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Please inspect your php scripts ajax response with your browser and post it here (at least structurally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, off, you don't need to specify column headers within your HTML. You may set those using `columns` / `columnDefs` options with `title` property. That way, you will not see the table with default styling before DataTable gets initialized. Your table markup may simply look like: `<table id="example" ...></table>`.

But that, of course, is not the root cause of your problem.

What looks suspicious to me is your SQL. It looks like you're referring twice to your `t_user` table: first time, by setting `$table` variable, second, with this part of your `$joinQuery` - `FROM 
 t_user`. So, if you have a chance to throw back the output of the query, say, with `var_dump()` in the appropriate place of your code, or `echo` the query itself to check its validity, I guess, that would've give you a hint.

Another thing you must be sure of, is that your SQL output contains the array of arrays or array of objects that correspond to your rows and either of those are encompassed within `data` / `aaData` of your output JSON. Otherwise, you may need to specify JSON property that holds your array within `ajax.dataSrc` option, or set it to empty string if your JSON is an array itself.